# I need new version of build-tools for sdk manager

Tags: java, android

i started working by sdk manager and android programming but my sdk manager doesn't have build-tools .I couldn't find it by searching.i use eclipse IDE too.

can anyone suggest me a website or download link of build-tools package?

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html

Comment: i checked it but i dont know where is download link?

Answer (score 0):

download and install android development kit ADT for eclipse that should do the trick